# Dart/Flutter How to use parameters from woocommerce API in dart application?

Tags: api, flutter, dart, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to use the parameters from the woocommerce documentation (https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#list-all-orders) but it is not changing the results in the flutter application!
I am using the end point: `var data = await wooCommerceAPI.getAsync("orders?filter[status]=pending");`